# Dev Noob - Can I use two output pins from an ESP32 to get a voltage of 7.2?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, series, esp32

I have an ESP32 and I would like to get an output voltage of more than 3.6 from its pins.

Would activating them at the same time and connecting them putting them in series make the voltage rise to 7.2 volts?

My idea would be to activate both of them at the same time, using diodes so no current flows into the other pins by accident.

What I am trying to do is to toggle a relay that needs a 5V signal.

Sort of schematics:

[image]

I am a software developer so I am a complete noob with electronics.

Comment: How do you intend to put them in series? Draw us a schematic.

Comment: Added the schematics although they are very dirty. I also thought how am I gonna power up the VCC pin :/ . I guess that @Justme's answer is what it makes most sense

Comment: That's connecting them in parallel, not in series.

Comment: Your schematic is fine, it's perfectly understandable :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to put IO pins in series, as they share the same ground.

To drive a relay, you need to do what everyone else does, drive a transistor with an IO pin, and then use the transistor to drive the relay.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, I'll have to investigate further